# Removing the occurances of the character

Tags: sql

I need to remove the occurance of the character '.'and the double quotes "" from the following titles of a book present in the table MAGAZINE."HUNTING THOREAU IN NEW HAMPSHIRE" THE ETHNIC NEIGHBORHOOD".

WHICH OF THE FOLLOWING IS CORRECT ONE?
Options are:

```
a- SELECT LTRIM(Title,"") FROM MAGAZINE    
b- SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Title,'.'"),"") FROM MAGAZINE
c- SELECT LTRIM(Title,"THE') FROM MAGAZINE
d- SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TITLE,'."THE'),"") FROM MAGAZINE
```

Comment: Have you tried these queries?  Maybe neither of them is what you need.

Comment: If this is a single book you'd better to manually update the record (or delete and re-insert)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no coding effort.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (and other SQL dialects) the LTRIM function removes leading spaces. Use the REPLACE function instead.

```
REPLACE(str, from_str, to_str)
```

In order to remove all the occurances of a character, replace this character by an empty string. Since you have to remove two characters, apply the function twice

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Title, '.', ''), '"', '')
FROM MAGAZINE
```

If you want remove leading and / or trailing characters other than spaces, use TRIM:

```
TRIM([{BOTH | LEADING | TRAILING} [remstr] FROM] str)
```

I.e. for a trailing '.': `TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM Title)`. Let's assume that you want to remove only the trailing '.' and, from the remaining string, the leading and trailing '"':

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM Title))
FROM MAGAZINE
```

See:

- [MySQL - String Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_replace) on tutorialspoint.
- [String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) in MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual on mysql.com